# Get all files in Documents folder besides .DS_Store?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am using this code to make an array with all the documents in the Documents folder of my app... Here is the code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);'
```

How do I exclude `.DS_Store` from the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't exclude the `.DS_Store` files with that method, unless you want to do a second step, and filter them out of your filePathsArray. If you want to do it one step, then use `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:`. You can pass nil for the properties and `NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles` for the options. You would also have to change the way you get path, and use `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` to get the URL of the documents directory.

Answer (score 1):

Will `enumeratorAtURL:` work for you? Here is the link http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/EnumADir.html

Comment: Not really... I have everything all set up, so I don't really want to add that.  Thanks for the suggestion though.